# np.poly1d: how to calculate R^2

Tags: numpy, linear-regression

I am fitting my data to a linear regression. But I want to know how to calculate the R2 values. The following is the code I have so far.

```
total_csv= pd.read_csv('IgG1_sigma_biospin_neg.csv',header=0).iloc[:,:]
x_values=(19,20,21,22)
y_values=IgG1_sigma_biospin_neg.loc[0, ['19-', '20-', '21-', '22-']].tolist()


my_fitting= np.polyfit(x_values,y_values,1)
my_lin_fitting = np.poly1d(my_fitting) 
my_x=Symbol('x')
print('my_equation:',expand(my_lin_fitting (my_x)))
```

I get the equation of the linear fitting of my data  35.6499591999999*x + 6018.6395529.

```
In [95]:y_values
Out[95]: [6698.0902240000005, 6733.253559000001, 6757.754712999999, 6808.75637]
```

Do you know how to calculate R2 values?

Comment: To calculate R-squared (R2) I use numpy's var() method as "R2 = 1.0 - (numpy.var(regression_error) / numpy.var(dependent_data))" and use it to tell me the fraction of dependent data variance (y_values variance) explained by the model.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Could you elaborate on what `regression_error` and `dependent_data` mean?

Comment: "regression_errors = predicted_values - y_values" and the dependent data is "y_values".

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledege, `np.polyfit` does not provide a coefficient of determination (R2).

The residual that Richard mentioned in his answer is something different, named Sum of Squares Error (SSE). More info about it here:
https://365datascience.com/tutorials/statistics-tutorials/sum-squares/

Good news is, you can easily calculate R2 from SSE. First you calculate the Sum of Square Total (SST), then the R2 is merely `R2 = 1 - SSE / SST`. (See above link for further explanations.)

```
import numpy as np 

# generate pseudo-data so the code can be run standalone (nicer for a mwe)
x_values = np.arange(100)
y_values = 3 * x_values + 2 + np.random.random(100)-0.5


my_fitting = np.polyfit(x_values, y_values, 1, full=True)
coeff = my_fitting[0]

### Residual or Sum of Square Error (SSE)
SSE = my_fitting[1][0]

### Determining the Sum of Square Total (SST)
## the squared differences between the observed dependent variable and its mean
diff = y_values - y_values.mean()
square_diff = diff ** 2
SST = square_diff.sum()

###  Now getting the coefficient of determination (R2)
R2 = 1 - SSE/SST 
print(R2)
```

Another approach is to use the already implemented function provided by Scikit-learn./

```
##  Alternative using sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

predict = np.poly1d(coeff)
R2 = r2_score(y_values, predict(x_values))
print(R2)
```

Both methods give me the very same answer.

Answer (score 0):

first thing - you should be using [np.polynomial.polynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit) Class/methods instead of np.polyfit (*see the doc's on np.polyfit, pointing people to use the newer code*)

You can then use the polyfit method there.  It will by default only return the coefficients.  If you want the residual (R2), then specify `full=True`.  polyfit will then also return a list, with the first element the residual (R2).  [See here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html)

The mod to your code above would be below:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly

my_fitting, stats = poly.polyfit(x_values,y_values,1, full=True)
R2 = stats[0][0]
```

Comment: I have the following message by running this code. `my_fitting, stats = np.polyfit(x_values,y_values,1, full=True)`    `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Sorry - my fault! ...my code above still was calling np.polyfit, not the polynomial library one!
I've updated the code to call poly.polyfit(), not np.polyfit()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code now runs. However, there must be some mathematical errors. R2 that I get is 131.76636504811702 above 1.

Comment: Maybe check you input values, and try plotting the line the coefficients return over them?  ...polyfit does work, and stats first element is the residual (R^2) value.

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66090745/25507), `stats[0][0]` gives the Sum of Squares Error (SSE), not R². SSE is used to calculate R², but it's not the same thing.